# How do I read database data from default User class in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, class, model

When I use the following code in my routes/web.php file, I keep getting the error of 'Trying to get property of non-object' each time I visit the /user/{id}/post url.

routes/web.php

```
use App\Post;
use App\User;

Route::get('/user/{id}/post', function($id) {
  return User::find($id)->name;
});
```

App/User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasOne('Post');
    }
}
```

App/Post.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    // protected $table = 'posts';

  use SoftDeletes;

  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
  protected $fillable = [''];
}
```

How do I view data stored in the table users? I put some dummy data in there to try and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user hasOne relation with Post,it is better to make relation `post()` rather than `posts()` and post belongsTo user.

**User Model:**

```
public function post() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
}
```

**Post Model:**

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    }
```

then, this gives all user's post along with user name.

```
$users=User::with('post')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
  print_r($user->name);
  print_r($user->post);
}
```